# Need help to convert PSD to PNG in GraphicsMagick

Tags: vmware, freebsd, psd, graphicsmagick

I am trying to convert PSD to PNG in GraphicsMagick by using the following command:

```
#gm convert file.psd -flatten file.png
```

Everything looks no problem while the web application is in stagging server.
When I move the web application to a production server, some of the PSD files will get the following error message:

```
In GraphicsMagick 1.3.12 : gm convert: Too much image data in file.
```

or this one:

```
In GraphicsMagick 1.2.10 : gm convert: Memory allocation failed (unable to allocate cache info) [Cannot allocate memory].
```

The most ridiculous part is it works in stagging server, but not works in production server.
The stagging servers are FreeBSD in VMWare, and the production servers are physical server.

There are very very few documentation I found on the Internet. Only a thread few months ago here: 
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=20110301013714.GC15521%40node99.net&forum_name=graphicsmagick-help

mentioned the same problem, but no reply.

I am wondering if I can get help here. Or maybe I am wrong, I should choose ImageMagick.

Comment: Do they have the same architecture? i386 or x86_64? Are Freebsd and GraphicsMagick the same on both servers? What is the memory size on both servers?

Comment: We saw the same error. in our case it occurred only on 64-bits, but not on 32-bits boxes. HTH

Comment: @Nico den Boer, Yes, you are right. I share the same opinion with you. It only occurred on 64-bits machine. GM is really unreliable. We moved to IM, and everything works. Till today, I made another test, GM is still buggy on 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the production server has a lower per-process memory limit, than your staging VM. That is, the limitation is, probably, imposed by software, rather than the actual hardware.

The limits can be per user (or, rather, [per user-class](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/users-limiting.html)) as well as system-wide (using sysctl). Try running

```
% sysctl -Aa|fgrep kern.max
```

and compare the outputs between the two servers (kern.maxdsiz and kern.maxssiz are of particular interest). Also, try simply to run limits as the web-server user:

```
% su          # become root
% su -m www   # become www
% limits
```

and, again, compare the output.

Finally, could it be, that your production server is simply using more memory (for other things, such as serving other content), whereas the staging system is only processing a single file-conversion and thus is not hitting a limit?

Comment: Hi Mikhail T, thank you for help. In this case, it is because GM is buggy on 64-bit. For simple PSD file, it works, but if the PSD file is more than 3 graphic layers on 64-bit machine, GM won't work.

Comment: Having maintained the GM port on FreeBSD some time ago, I have a healthy respect for the authors. I'm quite certain, if you report the bug to them, they'll fix it promptly.

Answer (score 0):

I've run up against this exact problem. It appears to be a limitation of graphicsmagick. If you use the -debug all switch you will see that the decoder for psd is trying to allocate more memory than is available per process.

For instance, I had a 6MB psd that I wanted to thumb into a jpg. GM was unable to do it because it was trying to inflate it out all at once and would need 64GB of ram (this is on my development machine which only has 8GB) .

I ran the same command on imagemagick and it worked no problem (on my development machine)